# Node: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I did some research on the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I understood the idea and what's causing it but I am not sure how to fix it for my controller code:

```
exports.isServerOnline = (req, res, next) => {
    const sock = new net.Socket();
    sock.setTimeout(2500);
    sock.on('connect', function () {
        sock.destroy();
        return res.json({
            "server": "online"
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        return res.json({
            "server": "offline"
        });
    }).on('timeout', function (e) {
        return res.json({
            "server": "offline"
        });
    }).connect(LS_PORT, LS_HOST);
}
```

I'm using socket to check if a remote host is up or down. Here is my client code (Vue.js):

```
created() {
    this.getServerStatus();
  },

  methods: {
    getServerStatus() {
      axios
        .get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL}/server/status`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.server === "online") {
            // no interesting code here
          } else {
            // no interesting code here
          }
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Complete error stack trace:

```
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743193+00:00 app[web.1]: _http_outgoing.js:518
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743201+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743202+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743202+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743204+00:00 app[web.1]: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743205+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743206+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743206+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:264:10)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743206+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/src/controllers/status.js:15:20)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743207+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743208+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743208+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743209+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
2020-07-02T07:40:47.743209+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could point me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that approach is correct mate. You are trying to create a socket inside http endpoint, that will not work. Here's gist I found that demonstrates using NodeJS Socket.

https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757

I'll recommend using into something like Socket.io. They have good amount of documentation to get off the ground.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your message. I've managed to get it to work. Apparently, all I had to do was to add sock.destroy(); in the timeout callback, according to the docs. For 'error', this is called automatically.